# Error: Cannot connect to firefox with selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

I am learning and doing automated testing.

I was able to connect Firefox with selenium in the project created but now on of the experienced developer has given his code to go through and implement automation testing as per his approach using( excel approach). But when I imported his code in eclipse and copy pasted my code for firefox connectivity it shows an error saying can't connect to localhost...and firefox binary issue as well.

I read about the error, it says that version upgrade or downgrade but the same code is working in my another project. Also, I added the jar files that I have in my project.

Please advice me on the same.

Comment: Share your code for better resolution?

Comment: Add your code, what you have tried to launch firefoxdriver. Which firefox version, Selenium version are you using?

Comment: Firefox recently changed the way it lets Selenium to connect (Marionette). Can your code connect to Chrome?

Comment: @PeterMasiar. I am to to connect selenium with firefox using (Marionette) but in my project . The problem is i have imported code of my manager to modify it but when i copy pasted same code into his project it shows an error. (cannot connect). I am using eclipse and both projects are there..one is running fine but another one says an error

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare one list and note down the configuration used by the team and cross verify weather those are available at your machine.

Selenium version have  continuous upgrade. So better to analyze which Selenium version compatible with the browser version and driver version

If no info available then

1. download latest Selenium jar files i.e. Selenium for Java 3.4.0 [from here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)
2. Upgrade your Firefox version to latest i.e 52.0.2
3. Download compatible `geckodriver` for Firefox i.e. `geckodriver.exe v0.18.0` [from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
4. Make sure you have  java 8 to use Selenium 3